# private function code is not called in swift

Tags: swift

I am debugging the following code. "@IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any)" runs when button was pushed. However, "private func imagePickerController" is not called. I set breakpoint in the "private func imagePickerController". but the program is not stopped. pelease help me.

Xcode: 12.3
swift version: unspecified

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] as? URL

    let completion: () -> () = { [weak self] in
        guard let url = self?.videoURL else { return }
        print(url)
        self?.playMovie(url)
        self?.frameoutput(url)
    }
    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
}

// MARK: - Private
//ビデオの再生部分
fileprivate func playMovie(_ url: URL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    
    present(playerViewController, animated: true){
        playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
//動画一覧表示
@IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"] // 動画のみ表示
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: There are no calls to the `imagePickerController` func. Why do you expect it to be called? You simply present a `UIViewController` variable called `imagePickerController`, but you never call `imagePickerController(_: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` is part of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, that should call the function, when picking an image. Is the image-picker presented, when `selectImage(:)` is called?

Comment: @Nino if the method is declared as `private`, it cannot be used for protocol conformance

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was expecting a conformance issue in that case. But didFinishPicking seems to be optional. The `private` function isn't visible to the imagePickerController and therefore cannot be called.